# Как написать адаптер jaxb для данных типа Date?

Tags: spring, jaxb

Приложение на Spring+jaxb.

В сущности есть поле типа Date

```
    @XmlElement(name = "TimeCalc")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    Date TimeCalc;
```

Как правильно написать jaxb адаптер для типа данных Date?

У меня есть черновой вариант, но не рабочий:

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:SSS");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.format(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.parse(v);
        }
    }
}
```

в переменную я пытаюсь распарсить и сложить

```
<TimeCalc>20181016T082849.000 GMT</TimeCalc>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не стоит игнорировать TimeZone

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS z");
```

Answer (score 0):

Рабочим вариантом является паттерн:

```
private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS 'GMT'");
```